# Facebook Invalid key hash issue. ( Redmi specific )

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, redmi-device

I can't get my app to allow Facebook to log in with my Redmi device. Every time the users tries to log in to Facebook and authenticate my app with their FB, it gives me this error:

> Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxx= does not match any stored
>   key hashes. configure your app key hashes at
>   http://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxx

Tested on Nexus & Motorola. No problems. Wonder if it is Redmi specific.

Any help would be great

Comment: Try to add that given hash key hash in facebook developer console.

Comment: already added. Please read my question again, I am getting the error on redmi device only. I tested on Nexus & Motorola and there is no problem.